# Split variable into several to get infos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I would like to separate this in Javascript and create variables infos1, infos2 ....

So I need a function to separate all the info.

```
<option value="[infos1][infos2][infos3][infos4]"></option>

var InfosInitial = $('#insert').find("option:selected").val();
```

var infos1 = ?;

var infos2 = ?;

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: there is not a lot of information on what you want to do, there is a lot of guess work for us to even start to answer the question

Comment: *`var infos1 = ?;`* - exactly. What do you expect to end up in `infos1`?

Comment: to add to that, do you need the variables to be dynamically created or do you have preset variables you want to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to do this. We will use the [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function in this example. It should look something like this:

```js
const InfosInitial = '[infos1][infos2][infos3][infos4]';
const info = InfosInitial.match(/(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/gm);
const infos1 = info[0];
const infos2 = info[1];
const infos3 = info[2];
const infos4 = info[3];
console.log(`${infos1}\n${infos2}\n${infos3}\n${infos4}`);
console.log('As an array:', info);
```

Also, I am just saying but having everything in 4 different variables is inefficient. So you should use the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is really hacky but you can add new variables to the window element like this

```
window['myVar'] = 'Hello, world!'
```

now you can call and redefine `myVar` by simply doing this

```
console.log(myVar)
// 'Hello, world!'

myVar = 42069
console.log(myVar)
// 42069
```

knowing this you can create a function where it gets the attribute 'value'

and split it between the ] and [ with `String.split()` remove the brackets and loop through the remainders

Comment: i hope i understood your question

Answer (score 0):

your question little unclear to me but I guess this is what you want.

```js
var InfosInitial = "[infos1][infos2][infos3][infos4]";
Array.from(InfosInitial.matchAll(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g)).forEach(value => {
    console.log("all = " + value[0] + ", value = " + value[1]);
})
```